# Why does 'require' keep on loading files as strings in the heap even though it's removed from de require.cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I have a NodeJS application that is like a task manager. Every second (using a rxjs timer), it fetches the tasks from the database that are scheduled. Every task has a filename and that file is loaded with `required`. Every file must have a `run()` method that executes the task. After the task is completed the required file is removed from `require.cache`. The application fails after a couple of days, because the heap is full. I've checked with `node --inspect` and saw that the required files are kept in the strings. Can somebody explain me why the required files are kept as strings on the heap, while the file is removed from the `require.cache`? And even better, if someone can explain to me how it can be solved it would be even better!

Below is a shortened version of my code

```
    async test() {
        timer(0, 1000).pipe(
            exhaustMap(async () => {
                return await this.executeTasks();
            })
        ).subscribe();
    }

    async executeTasks(): Promise<void> {
        // get all queue items
        const tasks = await this.getTasks();

        // for each item
        for (const task of tasks) {
            // execute item
            await this.executeTask(task);
        }

    }

    async executeTask(item: QueueItem) {

        try {
            const Callback: typeof AutomationCallback = require(item.callbackFile);
            const callback = new Callback();

            await callback.run();
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof Error && (error as any).code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
                log_message('Failed executing', item.callback, item.id, `Cannot find file ${item.callbackFile}`);
            } else if (error instanceof RescheduleError) {
                log_message('Failed executing', item.callback, item.id, error.message);
            } else {
                log_message('Failed executing', item.callback, item.id, (error as any).toString());
            }

        } finally {
            // remove require from cache;
            try {
                delete require.cache[require.resolve(item.callbackFile)];
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is a screenshot of a snapshot, the highlighted file is added to the heap everytime the file is loaded with `require`. As you can see on the left side the heap will slowly fill, time between snapshot 1 and 2 is probably 5 minutes.
[image: Screenshot of the heap]

Comment: As a temporary solution you could consider spawning a "worker" nodejs process to execute the file (e.g. using [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or similar). I don't know whether removing an entry from require.cache will actually free the memory that the entry takes. It is deleting a reference to it and objects are garbage collected when there are no more active references to them. It may be that there are still references to them (either yours or internal) you can use a WeakMap to verify.

Comment: @apokryfos Should I add the Callback class or the callback object to the weakmap? Or maybe both? Child process is an option, but it feels kinda hacky and with the extra overhead of loading another Node instance this can become really slow.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I have no doubt that the callback instance is eventually garbage collected, but how about the class? Wouldn't the definition persist indefinitely? If you can require a class from another file, delete the require.cache of that file and still be able to create instances of that class then that means there must be a reference to that class definition remaining active

Comment: So if I delete the cache right after the require I can still create a Callback instance and execute it. The Callback is in a variable, so eventually it will be garbage collected, if i'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is previously defined, why not have them required at top & call them conditionally?

Example:

```
class TaskRunnerBase {
  async run() { this.doRun(); }
  async doRun() {} // implemented by specific runners
}
class TaskRunnerA extends TaskRunnerBase {
  async doRun() {...} // custom implementation for TaskRunnerA
}
class TaskRunnerB extends TaskRunnerBase {
  async doRun() {...} // custom implementation for TaskRunnerB
}
class DefaultRunner extends TaskRunnerBase {
  async doRun() { console.log('Default Runner'); } 
}
```

TaskManager

```
const TaskRunnerA = require('./task-runners/task-runner-a');
const TaskRunnerB = require('./task-runners/task-runner-b');
// more runners
const DefaultRunner = require('./task-runners/default-runner');

...
...
async executeTask(item: QueueItem) {

        try {
            const Callback: typeof AutomationCallback = this.getRunnerByType(item.callbackFile);
            const callback = new Callback();

            await callback.run();
        } catch (error) {
            ...
        } finally {
            ...
        }
    }
    

getRunnerByType(type) {
  if(type === 'RunnerA') { // "RunnerA" for example
    return TaskRunnerA;
  }
  else if(type === 'RunnerB') { // "RunnerB" for example
    return TaskRunnerB;
  }
  ....
  else {
    return DefaultRunner; // If unknown type is passed, let's keep going, with DefaultRunner.
  }
}
```

This is kind of approach is simple, manageable & no brainer in a long run.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, and I've thought about this. The only problem is that I want to add new tasks when the process is running. I don't want to restart the task manager everytime I add a new task

Comment: @fieldhof, yes, if things are dynamic, this needs to be solved in the way you are attempting or you could use `Function` constructor or eval. It is possible to read the file contents as string & construct a function in run time or simply `eval` the contents. In this case using `eval` wouldn't be evil, unless you want the solution to be performant. If performance is needed, use `Function` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`require.cache` is not the only place where loaded modules are cached. There are a few more ones depending on the type of module and how it is loaded, and some of these objects are not even exposed by Node.js, meaning that you could not delete them if you wanted.

A well-documented example is [`module.children`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modulechildren), an array of loaded modules. If you look at the length of this array, you'll see that it gets larger and larger after each `require`, because a you are effectively loading the same modules over and over again, instead of reusing the cached objects:

```js
const Callback: typeof AutomationCallback = require(item.callbackFile);
console.log('Loaded modules:', module.children.length); // <-
const callback = new Callback();

await callback.run();
```

You could of course clear the children list (which is not used as a cache anyway) together with the `require` cache:

```js
// No guarantee that this will help.
delete require.cache[require.resolve(item.callbackFile)];
module.children.pop();
```

I even wrote [my own tool](https://github.com/fasttime/postrequire#readme) to do something like that in a way that doesn't affect the rest of the program.

Doing so may help or not, and in fact, it could be even counterproductive if the sole goal is to prevent memory leaks - by allocating resources to load a module every time the module is required.

Your best option is probably to get rid of the `finally` block and keep the `require.cache` unchanged. In this way, each module will be loaded at most once.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem.

I put the delete require.cache in it, because I want to change the file without restarting the service. It works wonderfully, apart from the memory leak. I will check the module.children to see if it grows